# Collecting pixel values in a line drawn using mouse

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I have an image (24 bit bmp) such as the following:

[image]

The user draws a line (shown here in red) using mouse. This line can be any where with any angle. Then he clicks right or left mouse button, and the image pixel values across the lines are stored in a file in addition to displaying on the console.

I have used `setMouseCallback()` for showing the position of the mouse (shown below ). But I need a little more help in understanding an elegant way for finding and storing the pixel values across the line. Kindly help!

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     }
     else if  ( event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Right button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     }

     else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
     {
          cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;

     }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

     Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Acme\\Desktop\\image-processing\\2.bmp");
     namedWindow(" Window", 1);
     setMouseCallback(" Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);
     imshow(" Window", img);
     waitKey(0);
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with, for example using the equation of a line to calculate the pixels through which the line passes?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator

Comment: Can't you use the line as a mask for the input image?

Comment: I would use the line iterator as berak suggests. Using the mask doesnt give any order yet and I guess constructing the line iteration will be as complex as drawing the line (if both algorithms use bresenham line algorithm).

Comment: @Micka am trying to use iterator but I am facing errors [Trying to understand the usage of Lineiterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488289/trying-to-understand-the-usage-of-lineiterator)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the line by *warping* it to a 1 x (linelength) or (linelength) x 1, vertical or horizontal Mat. Then you can easily read down or across pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

The specific details depend upon your program, but values is populated once two points are clicked. What you do after that is up to you.

```
cv::Point g_points[2];
int g_pointIndex;
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> values;
bool g_allGood = false;

void onMouse(int e, int x, int y, int d, void* ud)
{
    if (e != CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN || g_pointIndex >= 2)
        return;

    g_points[g_pointIndex++] = cv::Point(x, y);
}

void main()
{
    // load image as greyscale
    Mat img = imread("C:\\temp\\2.png", CV_8UC1);
    namedWindow("img", 1);

    setMouseCallback("img", onMouse);

    while (1)
    {
        // all points collected
        if (g_pointIndex == 2 && !g_allGood)
        {
            /*
            to save processing, i suggest you remove the mouse callback once all points
            are collected. do this with: setMouseCallback("img", NULL,NULL);
            */

            // create line iterator, and add pixel values to values vector
            cv::LineIterator it(img, g_points[0], g_points[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
                values.push_back((Vec3b)*it);

            // you now have all pixel values in values;
            g_allGood = true;
        }

        imshow("img", img);
        waitKey(100);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried printing the values in values: cout<<Mat(values)<<endl; , but it is empty

Comment: I've edited the code. ```values``` is populated with the values and is certainly not empty.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Actually now I get run time error, but no compilation error. I debugged it and It gives Unhandled exception when setMouseCallback() is called.

Comment: What's the exception? Look in the console window for more details