# Trying to understand the usage of Lineiterator

Tags: c++, opencv

Following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) article I am trying to understand how to work with lineiterator. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main( )
{

     Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Acme\\Desktop\\image-processing\\2.bmp");


LineIterator it(img, 1, 200, 8);
LineIterator it2 = it;

vector<Vec3b> buf(it.count);

for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
{
    buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;
printf("%d\n", buf[i]);

}

      return 0;

}
```

But It gives errors:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'cv::LineIterator::LineIterator(const cv::Mat &,cv::Point,cv::Point,int,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'cv::Point'  c:\users\acme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\iterator\opencv1\helloworld.cpp 15


Error   2   error C2100: illegal indirection    c:\users\acme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\iterator\opencv1\helloworld.cpp 22


3   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "cv::LineIterator::LineIterator" matches the argument list c:\users\acme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\iterator\opencv1\helloworld.cpp 15



4   IntelliSense: no operator "*" matches these operands    c:\users\acme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\iterator\opencv1\helloworld.cpp 22
```

I am expecting that buf would print me the values stored across the line. Can someone help me understand how to rectify this?

Comment: try `LineIterator it(img, cv::Point(startX,startY), cv::Point(endX,endY), 8);` instead. Have a look at this for an example: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator

Comment: @Micka this gives  error C2100: illegal indirection on  buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it; It also gives IntelliSense: no operator "*" matches these operands

Comment: Look at the example link. Dereferencing gives you not color values but pixel positions. You have to read their values from the image manually!

Comment: @Micka The code I have taken from the given example only. I did not get what is happening in this line:  buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;

Comment: my fault. looked at sample 2 which uses `img.at<Vec3b>(it2.pos())`. see beraks answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LineIterator it(img, Point(1,1), Point(20,20), 8);

vector<Vec3b> buf;   

for(int i=0; i<it.count; i++)
{
    buf.push_back( Vec3b(*it) );
    it++;
}

cerr << Mat(buf) << endl;
```

Comment: \*(const Vec3b\*)*it; // this works, i think this star is pretty darn important